# how to import and read multiple json files in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, file

I'm trying to read multiple json files using python.
My files look something like this:

- Inbox

  - Jack

    - message1.json
  - Brad

    - message1.json
  - Charles

    - message1.json
  - Emerson

    - message1.json
  - Luke

    - message1.json

As you can see, all the json files have the same name, it's just the folder that has a different name. Is there a way to read the inbox and iterate through each folder to get the json file?

So far I have this:

```
path = '/messages/inbox/'
file= '/message_1.json'
```

And was thinking something like this:

```
for i in <something?> :
   new_file = path + str(i) + file

with open('new_file', 'r') as myfile:
     data=myfile.read()

obj = json.loads(data)
```

I know this can't work because python needs to read the path first. How do I get the program to read the path and then iterate through it?

Thank you for taking the time read my question and help in any way you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `os.listdir("relative path to where the folders are")` [(take a look at the domumentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get all subdirectories in the cwd. And you should not use loads for getting the contents of a file, instead pass the file object to the [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) method. Implementing it in your code would be something like this:

```py
import os

for i in os.listdir(path) :
   new_file = path + i + file
   my_file = open(new_file,"r")
   obj = json.load(my_file)
   my_file.close()
```